# openAPI unable to resolve ref to external file. Component name contains invalid characters

Tags: json, yaml, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm trying to split a large yml into a bunch of smaller yml documents.  I followed the example provided by David Garcia [here](https://davidgarcia.dev/posts/how-to-split-open-api-spec-into-multiple-files/), and then using OpenAPI CodeGenerator to generate my models.  OpenAPI Generator complained that `[BUG] attribute components.schemas.Schema name doesn't adhere to regular expression ^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+$`.  So, I tried playing with David Garcia's example by cloning his repo and deploying locally, but I get the same error.  I decided to check it in the [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/), and I get the same issue, but the error message says

```
Semantic error at components.schemas.$ref
Component names can only contain the characters A-Z a-z 0-9 - . _
Jump to line 25
```

I'm using the yaml from David Garcia's example:

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
  description: Multi-file boilerplate for OpenAPI Specification.
  license:
    name: MIT
  contact:
    name: API Support
    url: http://www.example.com/support
    email: support@example.com
servers:
  - url: http://petstore.swagger.io/v1
tags:
  - name: pets
paths:
  /pets:
    $ref: "./resources/pets.yaml"
  /pets/{petId}:
    $ref: "./resources/pet.yaml"
components:
  parameters:
    $ref: "./parameters/_index.yaml"
  schemas:
    $ref: "./schemas/_index.yaml"
  responses:
    $ref: "./_index.yaml"
```

You can easily paste this into [the editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) and see the errors yourself.  The OpenAPI Specification says [components objects can either be an Object or a Reference](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.3.md#components-object), i.e. `Map[string, Schema Object | Reference Object]`, and the [Schema Object definition says](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.3.md#schemaObject), "Alternatively, any time a Schema Object can be used, a Reference Object can be used in its place. "

I'm aware that I can sub it down within the yaml document, like so:

```yaml
components:
  parameters:
    petId:
      $ref: "./parameters/path/petId.yaml"
  schemas:
    pets:
      $ref: "./schemas/Pets.yaml"
  responses:
    responseSchema:
      $ref: "./response/pets200.yaml"
```

But why can't I reference an external index?  The [online example](https://davidgarcia.dev/posts/how-to-split-open-api-spec-into-multiple-files/) says yes and the [open api spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.3.md#componentsObject) says yes, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a common misconception that the OpenAPI Specification allows `$ref` *anywhere*. Actually, `$ref` is only allowed in places where the OpenAPI Specification says the value of a field can be a "Reference Object" or a "Schema Object".

Specifically, this snippet is NOT valid OpenAPI syntax:

```
components:
  parameters:
    $ref: "./parameters/_index.yaml"
  schemas:
    $ref: "./schemas/_index.yaml"
  responses:
    $ref: "./_index.yaml"
```

`Map[string, Schema Object | Reference Object]` means that the `components.schemas` node must be a map where the keys are schema names and the values are either inline schemas or schema references. As in your second example (which is valid OpenAPI syntax):

```yaml
components:
  parameters:                              # Map
    petId:                                 #  <string, 
      $ref: "./parameters/path/petId.yaml" #           Reference Object>
  schemas:
    pets:
      $ref: "./schemas/Pets.yaml"
  responses:
    responseSchema:
      $ref: "./response/pets200.yaml"
```

The workaround that some implementations use to handle $refs in *any* places is to pre-process the spec using a generic JSON $ref resolver (such as [json-refs](https://github.com/whitlockjc/json-refs)) to resolve those non-standard $refs. For example, the [blog post](https://davidgarcia.dev/posts/how-to-split-open-api-spec-into-multiple-files/) you took this example from uses `swagger-cli` to resolve non-standard $refs and create a single merged file.

Comment: Thank you so much for this well structured response.  My mistake was in thinking that the `Map` contained either a key, value pair of `string, Schema Object` or a `Reference Object` that contained a map. I see my mistake now.  However, I really like the way that the components are able to be indexed like in the example from the blog.  I'm going to have to look into the OpenAPI Generator documentation and see if it can handle this in a similar fashion.

Comment: Hi @tbatch - Were you able to run this using openapi-generator-cli . Been trying with the above suggestions but still cannot able to generate the client using open-api spec file referencing external folders/files